# Basics of Simulated Annealing in Python

Tags: python

I have to use simulated annealing for a certain optimization problem. To get a 'feel' of the technique, I wrote a small python code and tried to run it. However, it doesn't seem to be giving satisfactory results.

```
import random;
import math;
from math import *;
LIMIT=100000;



def update_temperature(T,k):
    T1=T/log(k+1);
#   print "temp now is " + str(T1);
    return T1;

def get_neighbors(i,l):
    if(l>1):
        if(0<=i and i<l):
            if(i==0):
                return [1];
            if(i==l-1):
                return [l-2];
            return [i-1,i+1];
    return [];

def make_move(x,A,T):
    nhbs=get_neighbors(x,len(A));

    nhb=nhbs[random.choice(range(0,len(nhbs)))];


    delta=A[nhb]-A[x];

    if(delta < 0):
        return nhb;
    else:
        r=random.random();
        if(r <= (e**(-1*delta)/(T*1.0))):
            return nhb;

    return x;


def simulated_annealing(A):
    l=len(A);
    init_pos=random.choice(xrange(0,l));
    T=10000**30;
    k=1;

    x_best=init_pos;
    x=x_best;

    while(T>0.0000001 ):
        x=make_move(x,A,T);
        if(A[x] < A[x_best]):
            x_best=x;
        T=update_temperature(T,k);
        k+=1;

    return [x,x_best,init_pos];



def isminima_local(p,A):
    l=len(A);
    if(l==1 and p==0):
        return True;
    if(l>1):
        if(p==0):
            if(A[0] <=A[1]):
                return True;
        if(p==l-1):
            if(A[p-1] >=A[p]):
                return True;
        if(0<=p and p<l and A[p-1]>=A[p] and A[p]<=A[p+1]):
            return True;
    return False;


def func(x):
    F=sin(x);
    return F;

def initialize(l):
    A=[0]*l;
    for i in xrange(0,l):
        A[i]=func(i);
    return A;

def main():
    A=initialize(LIMIT);


    local_minima=[];
    for i in xrange(0,LIMIT):
        if( isminima_local(i,A)):
            local_minima.append([i,A[i]]);  
    sols=simulated_annealing(A);

    m,p=A[0],0;
    for i in xrange(1,LIMIT):
        if(m>A[i]):
            m=A[i];
            p=i;

    print "Global Minima at \n";
    print p,m;


    print "After annealing\n";

    print "Solution is " + str(sols[0]) + " " + str(A[sols[0]]);
    print "Best Solution is " + str(sols[1]) + " " + str(A[sols[1]]);
    print "Start Solution is " + str(sols[2]) + " " + str(A[sols[2]]);

    for i in xrange(0,len(local_minima)):
        if([sols[0],A[sols[0]]]==local_minima[i]):
            print "Solution in local Minima";
        if([sols[1],A[sols[1]]]==local_minima[i]):
            print "Best Solution in local Minima";
    for i in local_minima:
        print i;

main();
```

I am unable to understand where I am going wrong. Is there something wrong with the implementation or is there something wrong in my understanding about simulated annealing ? Please point out the error..

My rough idea about SA:
 Pick a random neighbor
 If neighbor improves your condition, move there,
 Else, move there with certain probability. 
 The probability is such that initially bad moves are 'allowed' but they are 'prohibited'   later on. Finally you will converge to your solution.

I have found the set of local minima and global minima using brute force. Then I run SA. I was expecting that SA will atleast converge to a local minima but that doesn't seem to be the case always. Also, I am not sure if at every step I choose a neighbor randomly and then try to move or I choose the **best** neighbor ( even if none of the neighbors improve my condition) and then try to move there.

Comment: It's easier to point out an error knowing how the actual results differ from your expected results. Can you be more descriptive?

Comment: I have modified my question a bit.

Answer (score 18):

For the most part, your code seems to work well. The main reason that it's slow to converge is that you only look at the two neighbors on either side of your current point: if you expand your search to include any point in A, or even just a wider neighborhood around your current point, you'll be able to move around the search space much more quickly.

Another trick with simulated annealing is determining how to adjust the temperature. You started with a very high temperature, where basically the optimizer would always move to the neighbor, no matter what the difference in the objective function value between the two points. This kind of random movement doesn't get you to a better point on average. The trick is finding a low enough starting temperature value such that the optimizer will move to better points significantly more often than it moves to worse points, but at the same time having a starting temperature that is high enough to allow the optimizer to explore the search space. As I mentioned in my first point, if the neighborhood that you select points from is too limited, then you'll never be able to properly explore the search space even if you have a good temperature schedule.

Your original code was somewhat hard to read, both because you used a lot of conventions that Python programmers try to avoid (e.g., semicolons at ends of lines), and because you did a few things that programmers in general try to avoid (e.g., using lowercase L as a variable name, which looks very similar to the numeral `1`). I rewrote your code to make it both more readable and more Pythonic (with the help of `autopep8`). Check out the [pep8 standard](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more information.

In `make_move`, my rewrite picks one random neighbor from across the whole search space. You can try rewriting it to look in an expanded local neighborhood of the current point, if you're interested in seeing how well that works (something between what you had done above and what I've done here).

```
import random
import math
LIMIT = 100000

def update_temperature(T, k):
    return T - 0.001

def get_neighbors(i, L):
    assert L > 1 and i >= 0 and i < L
    if i == 0:
        return [1]
    elif i == L - 1:
        return [L - 2]
    else:
        return [i - 1, i + 1]

def make_move(x, A, T):
    # nhbs = get_neighbors(x, len(A))
    # nhb = nhbs[random.choice(range(0, len(nhbs)))]
    nhb = random.choice(xrange(0, len(A))) # choose from all points

    delta = A[nhb] - A[x]

    if delta < 0:
        return nhb
    else:
        p = math.exp(-delta / T)
        return nhb if random.random() < p else x

def simulated_annealing(A):
    L = len(A)
    x0 = random.choice(xrange(0, L))
    T = 1.
    k = 1

    x = x0
    x_best = x0

    while T > 1e-3:
        x = make_move(x, A, T)
        if(A[x] < A[x_best]):
            x_best = x
        T = update_temperature(T, k)
        k += 1

    print "iterations:", k
    return x, x_best, x0

def isminima_local(p, A):
    return all(A[p] < A[i] for i in get_neighbors(p, len(A)))

def func(x):
    return math.sin((2 * math.pi / LIMIT) * x) + 0.001 * random.random()

def initialize(L):
    return map(func, xrange(0, L))

def main():
    A = initialize(LIMIT)

    local_minima = []
    for i in xrange(0, LIMIT):
        if(isminima_local(i, A)):
            local_minima.append([i, A[i]])

    x = 0
    y = A[x]
    for xi, yi in enumerate(A):
        if yi < y:
            x = xi
            y = yi
    global_minumum = x

    print "number of local minima: %d" % (len(local_minima))
    print "global minimum @%d = %0.3f" % (global_minumum, A[global_minumum])

    x, x_best, x0 = simulated_annealing(A)
    print "Solution is @%d = %0.3f" % (x, A[x])
    print "Best solution is @%d = %0.3f" % (x_best, A[x_best])
    print "Start solution is @%d = %0.3f" % (x0, A[x0])


main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It would be more helpful if you could say something more about how to choose the cooling schedule. Also, in a more general setting how does one decide if a feasible solution is a 'neighbor' of another feasible solution. Is it not that SA tries to do some kind of gradient decent but tries to escape out of the local traps by the using the probability expressions. Choosing a 'neighbor' from the entire search space works here but somehow seems to go against the notion of a 'neighbor'.

Comment: I'm not at all an expert on SA, so I can't give you a good answer on how to choose the cooling schedule. The exact answer is sure to depend on the problem, so you might want to try to find some papers related to your area of application or the type of objective function you have. You can also check out [adaptive SA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_simulated_annealing).

Comment: Choosing neighbors will also depend on your problem. The main reason to limit the neighborhood is so that once you've found a decent solution, even if you later move to a worse solution, you at least stay in the neighborhood. The intuition is that most objective functions are somewhat smooth, so good solutions will lie near other good solutions. So you need a neighborhood that's small enough to keep you near good solutions, but large enough to let you find them quickly. One thing you can try is decreasing the neighborhood over time (e.g. make it proportional to the temperature).